# How do I get the key of my most recent push ID from Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the most recent ID of from my orders table to that I can then use this ID in a path to get the order number and increment it by one.

```
  void _activateListeners() {

    final recentOrder = _readRef.child('Orders').limitToLast(1).get();
    final readOrder = _readRef
        .child('Orders/{$recentOrder}/orderNum')
        .onValue
        .listen((event) {
      final orderNum = event.snapshot.value;
      setState(() {
        lastOrderNum = orderNum.toString();
        intOrderNum = int.parse(lastOrderNum) + 1;
        newOrderNum = intOrderNum.toString();
      });
    });
  }
```

I know that I need to use the "key" word somehow but I have been unable to solve this problem.

my database table looks as follows:

```
Orders
    -N3ZdY6LOL_9Z-6KXHnK
              *cartProduct
              *dateTime:"2022-06-02 15:41:20.470139"
              *orderNum:"6"
              *totalAmount:45

   -N3ZdgEQIzsjLA5NCu3U
              *cartProduct
              *dateTime:"2022-06-02 15:41:20.470139"
              *orderNum:"7"
              *totalAmount:45
```

Edit: can someone tell me if it is even possible to fetch the unique push ID after it has been made (not directly after the order is added)? I have looked at all the documentation and I have failed to implement anything. I have also found numerous similar questions that are either just different or unanswered.

If I know SQL is SQLite a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the key from the snapshot by using the snapshot's [key](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot/key.html) property, like in this line below:

```dart
String? eventKey = event.snapshot.key;
```

Check out the documentation for Flutter's Realtime Database's [DataSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot-class.html) class for more information.

Comment: When I use this: ` final recentOrder =
        _readRef.child('Orders').limitToLast(1).onValue.listen((event) {
      String? keys = event.snapshot.key;`  it only ever returns "Orders" not the actual unique push() ID. How am I supposed to implement this piece of code?

Comment: That's because a query always returns a list of nodes. Even if there's only a single result, you'll get a list with 1 result. So you'd do `event.snapshot.children[0].key`

Comment: "children[0]" is not recognised with the square brackets only "children" which then does not allow ".key" to follow it. I don't think this is viable code in Flutter.